# Populate Combobox when opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down combobox. I would like the fields to be populated when I open the workbook; however, only the last chosen field is selectable, until the code is run.

How can I have the code run automatically when opening the workbook? Or is there an alternative way to do this?

The code that populates the combobox -when run- (which is written on the sheet which contains the combobox):

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Workbook_Open` event under the `Workbook` object to run the code everytime the workbook opens.

Comment: Yep, that did it. If you want to make this an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the procedure when the workbook opens will work like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MyProcedure
End Sub
```

This code must be in the workbook object.